# Is it possible to obtain an Oauth token inside Teams without reauthenticating?

Tags: microsoft-teams, microsoft-teams-js

If a user is already signed into Teams and they visit a Task Module React app, is it possible for the app to obtain an OAuth token without requiring the user to sign in again? I'm able to obtain a token using the `@microsoft/teams-js` node package, however this opens the browser and asks the user to sign in again which is bad user experience. Is there any way to avoid this? or will the app always require a user to sign in again

Comment: You can Add single sign-on to Teams app.
Microsoft Teams provides single sign-on (SSO) function for an app to obtain signed in Teams user token to access Microsoft Graph and other APIs. Teams Toolkit facilitates the interaction by abstracting some of the Microsoft Azure Active Directory (Azure AD) flows and integrations behind some simple APIs. This enables you to add SSO features easily to your Teams app.

Comment: SSO with Azure AD refreshes the authentication token in the background, which minimizes the number of times users need to enter their sign in credentials.
Reference Doc- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/toolkit/add-single-sign-on?pivots=visual-studio

Answer (score 0):

The user experience is a little different depending on which method you're using in the SDK to obtain the token.

Assuming you're using the latest SDK...

The preferred approach (where possible!) is to use `microsoftTeams.authentication.getAuthToken()` - this will ask Teams to request a token from AAD on your behalf for the current user. This will invoke a popup if consent for the basic scopes are required (offline_access, profile, email, openid - from memory) but this *should* only happen the first time a user accesses your app (or if an Admin deletes the Enterprise App in their AAD tenant... which does happen). This requires a little AAD configuration to allow the Teams client to request tokens on behalf of your application.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@microsoft/teams-js/authentication?view=msteams-client-js-latest#@microsoft-teams-js-authentication-getauthtoken

The other method is to use `microsoftTeams.authentication.authenticate()` - This will show a new window (because identity providers don't like iFrames) with your code that would typically use MSAL to redirect to the Microsoft login pages get a token in the same way you would for any SaaS solution. This method is also required if you want to get consent for additional scopes.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@microsoft/teams-js/authentication?view=msteams-client-js-latest#@microsoft-teams-js-authentication-authenticate

If you're seeing a login popup more than once (i.e. after the "first run" experience), I'm assuming you're using the second approach here?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Scott. Yep you're correct about me using the second approach there, as we do require an additional scope for SharePoint. Unfortunately it doesn't seem to work on mobile, as the redirection from Teams task module to web browser for authentication causes the React app to think token retrieval was unsuccessful. Unsure if there's a way around this given our task module was meant for mobile users using our chat bot. Thanks again

Comment: One quick question, I just wanted to confirm that Teams cannot obtain/generate any kind of token for a task module without the user logging in at least once (despite them already being logged into Teams) correct?

Comment: Using something like React can be a little tricky, however you can usually make it easier if you handle the "LoginStart" page (first page you show in the authentication popup) and "LoginEnd" page (The redirect page after consent happens) as pages outside of the React application then pass the token back via a call to `microsoftTeams.authentication.notifySuccess()`. The call to authenticate will pause until the popup has been closed.

Comment: You can ask Teams to obtain a token on your behalf using `getAuthToken()` - this token won't allow you to call Graph or Sharepoint though as the _audience_ claim will be your application (Client ID)... you'd need to use the (backend) on-behalf-of flow to get a delegated token for the user. If you require additional consent (which you will for the first time at least) you'll need to use the second approach.